# ReactJS Async - Using React Context to simulate a Singleton?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I currently have a hook:

```
function useFollowUser() {
    const isFollowing = useRef(false);

    return (userId) => {
       if(isFollowing.current) return; // mutual exclusion

       isFollowing.current = true;

       ... update DB and GUI

       isFollowing.current = false;
    }
}
```

Then, I use it in my FollowButton component

```
function FollowButton({ userId }) {
   ...
   
   const followUser = useFollowUser();

   const handleOnPress = () => followUser(userId);
  
   return <Button onPress={handleOnPress} text=... />
}
```

The problem is that, if in the same screen I have two instances of the same component, with the same userId prop, there will be some data inconsistencies, as the followUser method, if the user press both buttons at the same time, might run in parallel.

In order to resolve this async issue, is a good option to move the hook logic to a Context provider?

Any other approach?

Comment: Did you consider Redux

Comment: @iunfixit yeah, we will use it in a future, but for our first version, as is about to be finished, we are not using it.

Comment: Have you considered self executing functions that will wrap isFollowing variable? Basically make it global but under useFollowUser scope

Comment: @MistyK so, just moving the isFollowing flag to the global scope and remove it from the useRef right?

Comment: You need to keep thinking how to resolve async issue. For instance, why you run into this problem, and how do you make sure if two things happen in the same time, they don't conflict. My guts feeling, you might want to have an array to keep track of all existing `id` to make sure only one can be worked on at the same time? Also you can make one button disabled when the other one pressed.  In that case, you can have a context. Anyway, the logic isn't clear what you want to do at this point.

Comment: @Raul posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use context but simpler way is just to wrap isFollowing into same scope with self executing functions. Pay attention to two brackets that immediately invoke the function.

```
 const useFollowUser = (() => {
      let isFollowing = false;
    
      return () => {
     // this is hook context, you can use any effects here

        return (userId) => {
          if (isFollowing) return; // mutual exclusion
    
          isFollowing = true;
    
          // ... update DB and GUI
    
          isFollowing = false;
        };
      }
    })();
```

Usage:

```
const followUser = useFollowUser();
```

Comment: i think the main problem is that, after one `useId` is used, how could you prevent it to be used again? I don't know, i just sensed this might be the problem he's running into.

Comment: @windmaomao yeah, using a mutex array/map adds another level of atomicity. But, the main problem I was having was running multiple instances of the hook, thats why I was talking about using a context.

Comment: I don't want to be picky. But this isn't a hook :) This is only a function, that's why the proposed solution can work.

Comment: @windmaomao it is a hook. It is a function that is immediately invoked and returns a hook. You can use any hooks after return () => {